# Arabic permalink redirect to home page

Tags: permalinks, redirect, wp-config

I am working on Arabic wordpress website and I have a problem when using arabic title for the post. the single post page always redirect to home page but with english permalinks it work perfectly

My web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="WordPress Rule" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Unable to replicate using Nginx, this could be an IIS issue, but further information will be needed, such as what the query vars are ( install the Query Monitor plugin to see these )

Comment: did you follow up on [@tom-j-nowell](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/736/tom-j-nowell) suggestion?  Did you do a Network inspection using the page inspector in Firefox/Chrome to see the page code being returned?

Comment: Have you tried changing Permalink Settings to anything else? You can change it to a different pattern, save it and then change it back again.

Answer (score 1):

IIS has a problem with RTL-languages in URLs. Check your database and page encoding is UTF-8. After that try to put into `system.webServer` tag `<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="utf-8" />`

If it does not help you may use free WordPress plugin [Custom Transliteration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-transliteration/screenshots/) with [Arabic Transliteration](http://www.arabic-keyboard.org/arabic/arabic-transliteration.php)

Comment: thanks for your answe. `<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="utf-8" />` cause internal server error and the plugin solution didn't worked too :(